Symbolic solution of trigonometric equation
I am dealing with complicated trigonometric equations. Generally, I would like to calculate θ or at least Sin[θ].
My code is as follows
expr = Sqrt[α + β Cos[θ] + γ Sin[θ] + Sqrt[Γ + (a1 Cos[θ] - a2 Sin[θ])^2]]

Solve[expr == b, Sin[θ]]

With the above code, I receive output (as expected) as a function of Cos[θ]. Is it possible to somehow reduce it, that RHS is independent of θ?

you have typo. Sin\[Theta] should be Sin[ \[Theta] ]  May be copy/paste problem.

With so called  Weierstraß-transformation   θ -> 2 ArcTan[u] you get solutions for θ :
expr = Sqrt[α + β Cos[θ] + γ Sin[θ] + Sqrt[Γ + (a1 Cos[θ] - a2 Sin[θ])^2]]

transformation
{Cos[ θ], Sin[θ]} /.  θ -> 2 ArcTan[u] //TrigExpand // Simplify
rule = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {{Cos[ θ],Sin[θ]}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} /.  θ ->2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand //Simplify}]  (*{Cos[θ] -> (1 - u^2)/(1 + u^2), Sin[θ] -> (2 u)/(1 + u^2)}*)

solve for u (option Quartics -> False , thanks @Roman)
solu = Solve[(expr  /. rule )== b, u,Quartics->False] ; 
 


solution Sin[θ]
sinTheta= Sin[θ]/.rule/.solu


Weierstrass → Weierstraß

@Roman Thanks, corrected

Without goining into details I'm affraid your "symbolic solution" may be not only useless but also incorrect.  Having prescribed constants there might be no solutions, e.g. plotting expr With[{\[Alpha] = 1/2, \[Beta] = 1/3, \[Gamma] = 1/4, \[CapitalGamma] =     1/5, a1 = 3/3, a2 = 3/4} we can see there are no solutions for e.g.  b < 2/3.

@Artes Your criticism is incomprehensible! QP asked for a symbolic solution. Thereby your example "real solution only for b>2/3" is included in my symbolic solution.

By using Solve[(expr  /. rule )== b, u, Quartics -> False] the solutions look nicer, as expressed through Root objects being zeros of a quartic polynomial.

@UlrichNeumann  There is much to be improved, your answers are usually incomprhensible and it is not my interest to take care of quality of provided posts, but I believe that a long term user like you should provide higher standards of answers instead of big numbers of accidental, partial and shallow posts.  I hope this critics does  not discourage you but will be a soft promt toward higher quality of activity on this site.  There are many users here however all these advanced ones should set examples to follow, right?

@Artes My answer here is clear and comprehensible. No good style, if you use terms like "useless", "incomplete" , "There is much to be improved" without  reasoning. These kind of comments aren't qualified !

I'm maybe not a great judge of such things, but I found this response to be quite reasonable. What is it that's claimed to be amiss?

I opted to remove the Greek characters (though replacing the angle with a Greek cheese).
expr = Sqrt[
   alf + betty  Cos[feta] + gramma  Sin[feta] + 
    Sqrt[grampa + (a1  Cos[feta] - a2  Sin[feta])^2]];

Now we change the trigs to "neutral" expressions and add a defining polynomial to account for the identity satisfied by Sin and Cos. I often find this preferable to using the Weierstrass half-angle transformation, but maybe that's a matter of taste more than experience.
e2 = expr /. {Cos -> c, Sin -> s};
trigexprs = {e2, c[feta]^2 + s[feta]^2 - 1}
(* Out[24]= {[Sqrt](alf + betty c[feta] + gramma s[feta] + Sqrt[
grampa + (a1 c[feta] - a2 s[feta])^2]), -1 + c[feta]^2 + s[feta]^2} *)
From here it is easy to extract a quartic polynomial in the sine, with the cosine eliminated.
gb = GroebnerBasis[trigexprs, s[feta], c[feta]];
First[gb] /. s -> Sin

(* Out[26]= a1^4 - 2 a1^2 alf^2 + alf^4 - 2 a1^2 betty^2 - 
 2 alf^2 betty^2 + betty^4 + 2 a1^2 grampa - 2 alf^2 grampa - 
 2 betty^2 grampa + grampa^2 - 8 a1 a2 alf betty Sin[feta] - 
 4 a1^2 alf gramma Sin[feta] + 4 alf^3 gramma Sin[feta] - 
 4 alf betty^2 gramma Sin[feta] - 4 alf gramma grampa Sin[feta] - 
 2 a1^4 Sin[feta]^2 - 2 a1^2 a2^2 Sin[feta]^2 + 
 2 a1^2 alf^2 Sin[feta]^2 - 2 a2^2 alf^2 Sin[feta]^2 + 
 4 a1^2 betty^2 Sin[feta]^2 - 2 a2^2 betty^2 Sin[feta]^2 + 
 2 alf^2 betty^2 Sin[feta]^2 - 2 betty^4 Sin[feta]^2 - 
 8 a1 a2 betty gramma Sin[feta]^2 - 2 a1^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^2 + 
 6 alf^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^2 - 2 betty^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^2 - 
 2 a1^2 grampa Sin[feta]^2 + 2 a2^2 grampa Sin[feta]^2 + 
 2 betty^2 grampa Sin[feta]^2 - 2 gramma^2 grampa Sin[feta]^2 + 
 8 a1 a2 alf betty Sin[feta]^3 + 4 a1^2 alf gramma Sin[feta]^3 - 
 4 a2^2 alf gramma Sin[feta]^3 + 4 alf betty^2 gramma Sin[feta]^3 + 
 4 alf gramma^3 Sin[feta]^3 + a1^4 Sin[feta]^4 + 
 2 a1^2 a2^2 Sin[feta]^4 + a2^4 Sin[feta]^4 - 
 2 a1^2 betty^2 Sin[feta]^4 + 2 a2^2 betty^2 Sin[feta]^4 + 
 betty^4 Sin[feta]^4 + 8 a1 a2 betty gramma Sin[feta]^4 + 
 2 a1^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^4 - 2 a2^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^4 + 
 2 betty^2 gramma^2 Sin[feta]^4 + gramma^4 Sin[feta]^4 *)

This can be solved for if so desired. In which case I join @Roman in recommending to use Quartics->False.
